# Is there a reason my histogram bin spans multiple values, even though there is only one value in the dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram, geom-histogram

I have a df that looks like:

```r
df = data.frame(behavior = rep("proximity", 20),
                value = rep(-0.04280145, 20))
```

All the numeric values are the same and I want to make a very simple historgram. However, when I plot it, I get something like

```r
hist(df$value)
```

[image]

With `{ggplot2}` I tried:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
 geom_histogram(aes(x = value)
```

I am not sure why the bin spans so many values.

I was expecting on bar representative of `-0.042` with a count of `20`. I have tried adjusting bins, and binwidth, but I am at a loss.

Comment: `barplot(table(xyzzy$value))` where `xyzzy` is your data?

Comment: It's hard to know what might be going wrong when you don't share your code, but in general histograms **don't plot counts**, they plot a density. Perhaps you are looking for `geom_bar` to make a barplot instead?

Comment: I did post example code above. I'm working with the data frame: df <- data.frame(behavior = rep("proximity", 20), value = rep(-0.04280145, 20)). To produce a simple histogram: hist(df$value). I have also tried ggplot(df) + geom_histogram(aes(x=value). As I suggested, I am looking to plot a histogram, not a bar plot. I did try geom_bar and got a similar plot (also posted above).

Comment: `rep()` literally repeats the declared values and you have only assigned one value. You need `rnorm()`. Try something like `value = rnorm(100, mean = 60, sd = 5)`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I did that intentionally to mirror a much larger dataset I have with the same issue. All "value" are equal. I am not sure why the bar spans the x-axis, or why it is so wide. I was expecting a single bar at -0.0428.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? The secret is converting your value to a factor.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(behavior = rep("proximity", 20),
                value = rep(-0.04280145, 20))

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(factor(value))) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>